# SQL: Finding the total number of items for each category and ordering the result

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have the following table called Field:

```
Category       |     Industry     |  Company
Research             Science         Biolite
Retail               Healthcare      The Vitamin Shop
Crafts               Stationery      Art Centre
Research             Science         GeneSys
Retail               Healthcare      Live Healthy
Crafts               Stationery      Typewrite Pens
```

I want to be able to find the total number of companies per industry, and then order the result by Category and then Industry. (E.g. for Science there would be 2 companies, for Healthcare there would be 2 companies and for Stationery there would be 2 companies as well). The output should look like this (unordered):

```
Category  |  Industry    |   Number
Research     Science         2
Retail       Healthcare      2
Crafts       Stationery      2
```

I have the following query:

```
select t1.Category, t1.Industry, t2.Number from Field t1
inner join (
select Industry, count(*) as Number from Field
group by Industry
) t2
on t1.Industry = t2.Industry;
```

However, in the resulting table, in the Industry column, duplicate industries are shown (e.g. Science shows up twice). How can I get the Industry column to show each industry only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping by both Category and Industry:

```
select Category,Industry, count(*) as 'Number'
from Field
group by Category,Industry
```